# Form does not validate in Django

Tags: django, forms, validation

I have such a form as shown below.
When I click the "Add" button instead of the notification that the fields are required I get an error:

```
DoesNotExist at /users/add-to-group/
Group matching query does not exist.
```

**My form code**

```
class AddUserToGroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    group = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Group.objects.all(), required=True)
    user = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all(), required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['group', 'user']

    def has_group(self, user, group_name):
        group1 = Group.objects.get(name=group_name)
        return True if group1 in user.groups.all() else False

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(AddUserToGroupForm, self).clean()
        g = Group.objects.get(name=cleaned_data.get('group'))
        g.user_set.add(cleaned_data.get('user'))
        if self.has_group(cleaned_data.get('user'), cleaned_data.get('group')):
            self.add_error('user', "This user is already in group.")
        return cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cleaned_data` contains the `Group` instance, not the name of the `Group`.  So you shouldn't use this query:

```
Group.objects.get(name=cleaned_data.get('group'))
```

Just assign the group instance to the `g` variable:

```
g = cleaned_data.get('group')
```

The same issue you have in the `has_group` function.  `group_name` argument is a `Group`.  The code should be:

```
def has_group(self, user, group):
    return group in user.groups.all()
```

**UPDATE**:  If the user don't choose any group or user on the form the the `cleaned_data` don't contain the `group`/`user` values.  So you have to check this case in the `clean()` method:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(AddUserToGroupForm, self).clean()
    group = cleaned_data.get('group')
    user = cleaned_data.get('user')
    if group and user:
        if self.has_group(user, group)):
            self.add_error('user', "This user is already in group.")
    return cleaned_data
```

And you shouldn't call `group.user_set.add(user)` in the `clean()`.  This call has to be invoked from the form's `save()` method.

Comment: Now I get: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user_set'`